# Can a Finite Automata exist without any final state?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory, automata

It doesn't make sense to construct a language acceptor which does not able to accept any language. I specifically talking about FA which accept languages not transducer or translator which translate languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not just that it can exist - it is even necessary: how else would one accept the empty set, which is one of the regular languages. Unless you use an automaton with unaccessible states, which is pretty similar to not having a final state.

Comment: Thanks, I never think of empty set as a case.

Comment: Well, it is not the most useful case - but many times mathematically necessary according to the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

People build them all the time. You have a set of states, and each state is accessible ultimately from every other, and there is no final state, so it never halts, though it might get stuck in a cycling loop. No issue with that at all.

Do a search on "busy beaver".

Answer (score 1):

The [mathematical model of a FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model), as described on the wikipedia page, notes that the set *F* of final states may be empty. While an empty set of final states isn't much use if the FSM is used as a recogniser, FSMs can also be used as transducers.

For example, a [Mealy machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine) doesn't include a set of final states, since it the output from the machine as the  input is processed which is of interest.